# printf each sum in every loop at the end of code

Tags: c, arrays, loops

Print sum of N integer numbers.

*Input:*

The first line contains integer 1 ≤ T ≤ 100, denoting the number of test cases. Each case start with a number N, and the second line contains N integers separated by one space character.

*Output:*

T lines, in each line, print sum of input numbers.

Sample Input

```
2
5
54 78 0 4 9
3
1 2 3
```

Sample Output

```
145
6
```

This what I tried But I don't want to print the answer in each test case, instead I want to print the Grand Total at the very end.

My code, as it stands now :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int T, N, test, array[20], sum[20];
    do {
        printf ("How Many Test Case \n");
        scanf ("%d", &T);
        if (T<1 || T>100){
            printf ("Please Input Integer 0<T<100 \n");
        }
    }    while (T<1 || T>100);

    for (test=0; test<T ; test++){
        printf ("How many Integers to sum? \n");
        scanf ("%d", &N);
        int i=0;
        while(i<N)
        scanf("%d",&array[i++]);

        int m=0, sum=0;
        for (m=0; m<N; m++)
        {
            sum = sum + array[m];
            printf ("%d\n", sum);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are asking, could you clarify please? You want to move the `printf()` statement outside of the `for` loop, so why don't you just do that? that's what I understood from the question, I might be wrong, but to me, it's not clear what you want to ask.

Comment: Yes I want make it printf outside loop, but in question, I want answer(sum) for each test, at the end after done all input let say I make 100 test,

Answer (score 2):

You need to do three things.

1. Get rid of the `printf()` which is printing `sum` in the `for` loop.
2. Define one variable, (maybe `superSum`), and add up the *final* `sum`s to `superSum`.
3. Print the `superSum` before `return 0;`

Comment: I dont get you, supersum will print just one line or all test(all array), Could you make in code

Comment: @ammar0466 You should make it print only the _grand total_. I'll try to provide a working example, if that hepls. Give me some time. :-)

Comment: no I don't want supersum, 
I want differentiate the pre and post sum, 
but I don't want pre-print before next calculation. 
I want make it print all answer after I done all input. could you make into code thank you for understanding me

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to print the answer/sum for each calculation until you have the total sum, you need to not print inside your `for` loop condition:

```
for (m=0; m<N; m++)
{
   sum = sum + array[m];
}
printf ("%d\n", sum); //This will print total sum since it is after for loop calculation.
```

This way you do not need to create a new variable, but can reuse the same `sum` variable since its value continue be added in the `for` loop.

Comment: but I have many sum, in the question I have 2 set of number, so I should get 2 sum, how about if I made 100 sum[100], how to call each sum outside the loop.

Comment: @ammar0466 I dont understand what you're talking about. You have many numbers in your array that you are adding to `sum`, but you only have one total `sum`. If you want to differentiate the pre and post `sum`, that's fine. You can pre-print `sum` before doing the calculation. But im not quite sure if this is what you're talking about.

Comment: yes I want differentiate the pre and post sum,
but I don't want pre-print before next calculation. 
I want make it print all answer after I done all input.
could you make into code thank you for understanding me